# Assign Missing End Dates based on another date in group

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataset similar to this

```
id <- c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B2","B2","C1", "C2")
date_start <- as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-10", "2022-05-23","2023-01-02", "2022-07-19","2022-12-07", "2023-03-23"))
date_end <- as.Date(c("2022-01-05", NA, "2022-04-13", NA, NA, "2023-10-06", "2023-01-18", "2023-08-15"))

df <- data.frame(id, date_start, date_end)

tibble(df)
```

You can see that the date_end column has NA values which I would like to fill in with an appropriate date. The intention is to look at the next date_start variable in the group and fill in the previous date_end with a date less a day and if there is no acceptable date to fill add a year to the date_start for the date_end instead.

I can not come up with a solution, and was hoping for some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with an `if_else` statmentent:

```
library(dplyr) #> 1.1.0
df %>%
  mutate(date_end = if_else(is.na(date_end), 
                       lead(date_start - days(1), default = last(date_start) + years(1)), 
                       date_end), .by=id)

 id date_start   date_end
1 A1 2022-01-01 2022-01-05
2 A1 2022-01-06 2022-01-09
3 A1 2022-01-10 2022-04-13
4 A1 2022-05-23 2023-05-23
5 B2 2023-01-02 2022-07-18
6 B2 2022-07-19 2023-10-06
7 C1 2022-12-07 2023-01-18
8 C2 2023-03-23 2023-08-15
```

Comment: ``last(date_start)``?? why `last`? I see what you are doing, but I think your are complicating it beyond what it needs to be.

Comment: No it is not last(date_start), it should be the default of `lead()`!

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. ```lead(date_start - days(1), default = date_start + years(1))``` this works. No need for `last()` in the `default`.

Comment: This is in case of two consecutive NA's. The quasi shortform for `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(
  date_end = if_else(is.na(date_end), lead(date_start - days(1)), date_end),
  date_end = if_else(is.na(date_end), date_start + years(1), date_end)
)`

Comment: I am sorry but I can't make your code run?! using `df %>%
  mutate(date_end = if_else(is.na(date_end), 
                            lead(date_start - days(1), default = date_start + years(1)), 
                            date_end), .by=id)` I get Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `date_end = if_else(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `id = "A1"`.
Caused by error in `lead()`:
! `default` must have size 1, not size 4.

Comment: I just realized that you have `if_else` not `ifelse`. And the problem with `ifelse` is that it would turn the dates to numeric. This works: ```mutate(date_end = as.Date(ifelse(is.na(date_end), 
                                   lead(date_start - days(1), default = date_start + years(1)),
                                   date_end), origin = "1970-01-01"))``` but it is not necessarily better. Sorry for the fuss. Carry on.

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(date_end=coalesce(date_end,lead(date_start-1),date_start+years(1)))

# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   id [4]
  id    date_start date_end  
  <chr> <date>     <date>    
1 A1    2022-01-01 2022-01-05
2 A1    2022-01-06 2022-01-09
3 A1    2022-01-10 2022-04-13
4 A1    2022-05-23 2023-05-23
5 B2    2023-01-02 2022-07-18
6 B2    2022-07-19 2023-10-06
7 C1    2022-12-07 2023-01-18
8 C2    2023-03-23 2023-08-15
```

if you have the newer tidyverse package:

```
df %>%
  mutate(date_end = 
           coalesce(date_end, lead(date_start-1),  date_start + years(1)), 
         .by = id)
```

Comment: This method works well! The method below is slightly faster with the actual dataset I am working with though, so I would consider using that one if you have a larger DF.